# Threads syncronization in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a 3D grid of 3D blocks, and within each block I need to compute sequentially on the "z" layers of the block. In other words, I want to execute first all (x,y,0) threads, then all (x,y,1), etc. I need to execute my threads layer by layer (counting layers by axis z). I know about the function __syncthreads(), but I don't know how to syncronize threads with it the way I want.

UPD:

```
 __global__ void Kernel(//some params)
 {


      //some code 
      __syncthreads();
 }
```

It syncronizes all the threads in the block. But I need to execute all the threads where z = 0, then all the threads where z=1, etc.

Comment: This question needs more detail, but I suspect the answer is: define your thread block to the size of the groups of threads that need to synchronize. In other words, split your layers into separate blocks.

Comment: @harrism, I know that I can do so. But in this case, I'll have to launch the kernel a few times and this will have a negative effect on the performance.

Comment: Why do you need to launch the kernel a few times? You could have a 2D grid where the Y dimension represents the (former) Z layers in your blocks. And use 2D x/y blocks within the grid.  Then you only need __syncthreads() within the block, and the blockIdx.y corresponds to what you previously had in threadIdx.z...

Comment: @harrism, because I do have a 3D grid in my algorithm.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. You should put that in the question.

Comment: I edited the question to be a bit more clear.  Now that I understand, I think this is a reasonable question and I hope the down-voter can upvote (and remove the close recommendation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple loop, and specify the threads you want to do the work in each iteration. Something like:

```
for (int z = 0; z < zmax; z++) {
    if (threadIdx.z == z) { 
        //do whatever with x and y
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

In each iteration, threads with a specific z-index execute the instructions, while the others are idle; at the end of each iteration all threads synchronize.

Comment: Are you sure it will work? It seems this can garantee that all the threads with the same z will be syncronized, but it can't garantee that they will be excuted in the ascending order of z. First, threads where z = 0, then z = 1, etc.

Comment: @harrism, as far as I can see it's not about a safe or an unsafe use, This would probably entail the wrong result. It is quite possible that all the threads with z = 1 come to its sync point before the  threads where z = 0. Hence layer 1 would be executed earlier than layer 0. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Max `__syncthreads()` waits for all the threads to reach that line before execution continues. So all threads enter the loop, and in the first iteration only the threads with `threadIdx.z==0` do the work, while the others are idle. At the end of the loop, all threads synchonize. As for its safe-ness, I can't see why it is not safe (assuming all your threads enter the loop), but then again I'm no expert.

Comment: The way your code was written, your __syncthreads() was the only thing inside the if(), which is why I said it was unsafe (only threadId.z == z threads would sync).  I misunderstood that you meant for your C++ comment to be executable code. My bad for parsing like a compiler! I've edited your code to make it more correct, and changed my down vote to an up vote.  However I ask that you add a prose explanation to the answer to clarify how the code solves the problem.

Comment: @Noel, thank you very much. It really helped. Myself I always use brackets and that is why I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

`__syncthreads()` blocks the threads within a block. If you insist on using `__syncthreads()` you would have to ensure that the block size is the same as a(x*y), which is not necessarily possible, and even then, the order of the blocks isn't guaranteed. An alternative way of obtaining your goal, would be to launch a kernel per layer, and sync between kernels (i.e. block kernel concurrency). That of course really depends on what your exact kernel does and if breaking it up like that is feasible.

Comment: I'm not sure you got me right. For example, I have one  2 x 2 x 2  block. First I need to exectute the following threads : (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0),(1,1,0). It's the first layer. The second is (0,0,1), (1,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1). So for the first layer z = 0 and for the second one z = 1.

Comment: @Max Yes, I got that. The first kernel will handle the first layer (I assume that each layer is slightly bigger than 2x2); the second layer, the second, etc. The n-th layer handles (x,y,n).

Comment: I think this is possibly overkill, see my comment above about using a 2D grid of 2D blocks instead of launching multiple times.

Comment: @harrism Hard to argue with you, but I'll give it a shot. As I understand, OP asked that all the threads that deal with layer `n` be done _before_ the first thread of layer `n+1`. That being the case, even a naive representation ([fig. 5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#scalable-programming-model)) has multiple blocks running on each SM. Hence, different layers will run in parallel. I think that your first comment to OP missed the requirement(?) that each layer run separately. I do agree that my suggestion might be overkill and incurs a lot of overhead.

Comment: Yep, I missed the word "then" in the OP!